# Do I have to prepare wizards level 2 encounter spells?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, powers

I have a level 2 Wizard. Player's handbook on page 158 says:

> After an extended rest, you can prepare a number of daily and utility spells according to what you can cast per day for your level. You can’t prepare the same spell twice.

So, as far as I understand I have to prepare utility spell to use. And at level two I can have one utility spell prepared. Then, "Attack powers and utility powers" insert on p. 15 says:

> You can use encounter powers many times during a day of adventuring, but you have to rest a few minutes between each use, so you can use them each once per encounter.

and similar on p. 54:

> An encounter power can be used once per encounter. You need to take a short rest before you can use one again.

Which to my understanding allows me to use *any* encounter power during a day (am I wrong here? Character sheet having separate sections for encounter and utility powers kind of supports me here).

Now, level 2 wizard gets access to the following "Wizard Utility 2" spells: Jump and Shield. Both have "Encounter" keyword. Do I still must prepare only one of these on any given day (and hence I can only use one of them multiple times on any give day) or I can use both at any given day any number of times (while honoring the "Encounter" restriction)?

Answer (score 4):

## You may prepare only one of the two at a time.

The Wizard's capacity to 'prepare' spells permits him to establish a small pool of powers that he can switch in and out at faster rate than once-per-level, but it isn't intended to give him any more powers *on hand* than another character of equal level.

Comment: This answer could be strengthened by quoting the part of the book that describes the wizard's two-powers-per-power-but-only-one-prepared-at-a-time thing, and specifies how often they can be switched out.

Answer (score 2):

There are four types of powers with three types of usage keywords and not all characters will have access to all of them. At-will attack powers, Encounter attack powers, Daily attack powers and Utility powers. Utility powers can have any of the usage keywords (at-will, encounter or daily), and for most characters they can be tracked just according to usage.

The wizard prepares spells from a spellbook as part of the Spellbook class feature. It says in part:

> *Your  spellbook also holds your daily and utility spells.* You begin knowing two daily spells, one of which you can use on any given day. Each time you gain a level that lets you select a daily spell or a utility spell, choose two different daily spells or utility spells of that level to add to your book. After an extended rest, you can prepare a number of daily and utility spells according to what you can cast per day for your level. You can’t prepare the same spell twice. If you replace a spell because of gaining a level or through retraining, the previous  spell vanishes from your spellbook and is replaced by the new spell.

At second level a wizard can only prepare one daily (attack power) spell and one utility spell (regardless of usage type). Essentially, you can only cast one of those spells because the other one is held in your spellbook and not prepared for your use.

Comment: You say "There are three types of powers", and then list 4 power types :)

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed it to clarify that I meant three types of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I had it figured out.

First, regarding usage of "daily" and "utility". According to p. 54 of Player's Handbook:

> Power Types and Usage
>
> Every class has access to a mix of attack powers (used to harm your enemies in combat, more or less directly) and utility powers (used to overcome a variety of obstacles both in and out of combat). Within each type, different powers have different restrictions on how often you can use them: at-will, encounter, or daily.
>
> [...]
>
> The first line of a power description gives the name of the power, the class it’s associated with, the kind of power it is (attack or utility), and the power’s level (or the fact that it’s a class feature).

So, there are two separate categories:

1. Power type or power kind (as referred in last quoted paragraph) which can be
   either `attack` or `utility`
2. Restriction on how often power can be used ("Usage keyword"): `at-will`, `encounter` and `daily`.

These are unrelated to each other and power may have any combination of thereof (although there are no at-will utility powers).

The following paragraph:

> Daily and Utility Spells: Your spellbook also holds your daily and utility spells. You begin knowing two daily spells, one of which you can use on any given day. Each time you gain a level that lets you select a daily spell or a utility spell, choose two different daily spells or utility spells of that level to add to your book. After an extended rest, you can prepare a number of
> daily and utility spells according to what you can cast per day for your level.

on page 158 seem to refer to "daily attack spells" and "*any* utility spells" respectively and disallows usage of both "Jump" and "Shield" on the same day as only one of them can be prepared by level 2 wizard.
(That's the weakest part of the reasoning, as I speculate about what it refers to, but all other option make much less sense).

Comment: This answer would be strengthened by quoting the parts of the text that lead you to this conclusion.